# Integral vanishes on all intervals implies the function is a.e. zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am having trouble with the following problem:

> $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function such that for all $a$:
>   $$\int_{[0,a]}f\,dm=0.$$
>   Prove that $f=0$ for $m$ almost every $x$ (here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure).

I have no problem proving this for $f$ non-negative, or under the assumption that $f$ is integrable. But the question only assumes that $f$ is measurable and no more.

My idea was the usual thing; we look at the set of points where $f$ is positive and negative and assume one of these has measure greater than zero. Then I wanted to estimate one of these by an open set, look at the integral on the open set and show that it had to be greater than zero, a contradiction. But a key part of this attack is the assumption of the absolute continuity of the integral, which only holds in the case where $f$ is integrable.

Alternatively, if it were integrable one could simply estimate $f$ by a continuous function, where the result is quite obvious.

Ultimately we are going to show that $f$ is integrable, but it is not clear to me how to show this before showing it is zero a.e. So there must be a simpler way. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean to integrate over $[0,a]$? Otherwise one can take $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq0$. Then the hypothesis is true while the conclusion fails.

Comment: It says for all $a$, which I take to mean the interval $[a,0]$ when $a<0$ and $[0,a]$ when $a>0$.

Comment: I see. I took it to mean $\varnothing$ for $a<0$. I'll consider what you've said, though.

Comment: Is the function assumed locally integrable?

Comment: The assumptions are only that it is measurable and that its integral vanishes on intervals.

Comment: [Lusin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin%27s_theorem) might help as it allows you to establish that measurable functions are almost continuous.

Comment: Maybe the it's _implicitely_ assumed that $f$ is locally integrable, in order to ensure the existence of $\int_{[0,a]}fdm$.

Comment: I provided an answer; but here, the observation to make is that the symbol $\int_0^a f$ is defined. This means that at least one of $\int_0^a f^+$ or  $\int_0^a f^-$ is finite (the Lebesgue integral is not defined if we don't have this). But as $\int_0^a f$ is also finite, it follows that both $\int_0^a f^+$ or  $\int_0^a f^-$ are finite; and thus $\int_0^a|f|$ is finite. So, you do have $f\in L_1[0,a]$ for any $a$.  Note the term "integrable", as usually used, does not exclude the possibility that the integral is infinite.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The function $f$ must be integrable (one of $\int f^+$ or $\int f^-$ is finite) in order for the symbol $\int f$ to be defined. So, I'll assume this is the case. In fact, then, since $\int_0^a f$ exists and is finite for any $a$, it follows that $\int_c^d |f|<\infty$ for any numbers $c$, $d$.

We show $f$ is almost everywhere
 $0$ on any interval $[c,d]$; this will imply the desired result.

Suppose $f>0$ on the set of positive measure $E\subset[c,d]$. Choose a closed subset $F$ of $E$ with positive measure. We then have $\int_F f>0$. Now let $U=[c,d]\setminus F$. As $U$ is open, we may write $U$ as a disjoint union of open intervals: $U=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (a_k,b_k)$.

Now, since $\int_c^d |f|<\infty$
$$
0=\int_{[c,d]}f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{a_k}^{b_k}f+\int_F f.
$$
Since $\int_F f>0$, it follows that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\int_{a_k}^{b_k}f$ is negative. But then $\int_{a_n}^{b_n} f$ must be negative for some $n$.  However, this proves untenable upon observing that
$$
\int_{a_n}^{b_n} f =\int_0^{b_n} f - \int_0^{a_n} f =0.
$$

Similarly, one can show $f$ cannot be negative on a set of positive measure.

Comment: Thanks! I was totally overlooking that it IS locally integrable for the question to even mean anything.

Comment: Does this proof go through with minor adjustments even if we assume just $\int_{[0,a]} f dm = 0$ for all $a \in A$ where $\lambda([0,\infty) \setminus A) = 0$, i.e. all $a$ except the ones in a set of Lebesgue measure zero??

Answer (score 9):

*Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ System theorem*, as a strategic approach, works perfectly to conclude that the problem is true for all measurable sets !

Let $\mathcal{A}=$*"set of intervals"* which is a $\pi$*-system* and $\mathcal{L}=\{A\in\mathcal{F};\;\int_A f=0\}$ which is a $\lambda$*-system*. Hence,
$$\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})\subseteq\mathcal{L}$$
It means for each *Borel-set* $B$ : $\displaystyle \int_B f = 0$

Now use this fact that any *measurable* set differs from a *Borel-measurable* set by a *Zero-set*.

---

To finish the proof, see : [Showing that $f = 0 $ a.e. if for any measurable set $E$, $\int_E f = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219738/76758)

Comment: This is much underrated and one of my personal favourite methods. I don't see people use this too much.

Answer (score -3):

Any measurable function is uniformly approximated by continuous function on $(a, b)$. given statement is true for any continuous function and hence it is true for uniform limit of continuous functions, that is for measurable function

Comment: Which theorems are you using there?

Comment: It is *not* true that any measurable function is uniformly approximated by continuous functions.