# Question about proof of completeness of the Walsh system

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In a [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=PEjmQThw8xEC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=walsh%20system%20completeness%20proof&source=bl&ots=bBrX-5-DFe&sig=0NS61vLOHuMx0kHbATsiO4TJBSE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMraWrsKvUAhUBMZoKHWPLB88Q6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=walsh%20system%20completeness%20proof&f=false) "Completeness and Basis Properties of Sets of Special Functions" by J.R.Higgins there is a proof of completeness of the Walsh system and I don't comprehend one point in it.

> To satisfy the definition of completeness, let $f\in L^2(0,1)$ and set
>   $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, then $F(0) = 0$.
>
> Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)w_{k+1}(x)dx = 0 \; (k=0,1,..)$ then $$
>  \int_0^1 f(x)w_1(x)dx = 0 = F(1)\\ \int_0^1 f(x)w_2(x)dx = 0 =
>  2\left[F(1/4)+F(3/4)\right] = 0\\ \int_0^1 f(x)w_3(x)dx = 0 =
>  2\left[F(1/4)-F(3/4)\right] = 0 $$ whence $F(1/4)=F(3/4)=0$.
>   Continuing in this way for $w_4, w_5, w_6, w_7$ yields $$ F(1/8) = F(3/8) = F(5/8) = F(7/8) $$ In general we see that $F=0$ on a dense
>   subset of $(0,1)$. By continuity $F=0, f(x)=0$ a.e. and the proof is
>   complete.

**QUESTION:**

We assume that all projections of $f(x)$ are zero, for example $\int_0^1 f(x)w_2(x)dx = 0$. How do we get $2\left[F(1/4)+F(3/4)\right] = 0$ since $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$?

**USEFUL LINKS:**

[Integral vanishes on all intervals implies the function is a.e. zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274702/integral-vanishes-on-all-intervals-implies-the-function-is-a-e-zero)

Comment: When you mention a book, please name the authors and the title. Links stop working and other catastrophes do happen, and then your question would be incomplete.