# Riemann-Liouville integral of $f$ is zero implies $f =0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

The Riemann-Liouville integral is defined by
$$
I^\alpha f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_a^x f(t)(x-t)^{\alpha-1} d t
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function and $a$ is an arbitrary but fixed base point. Take $a = 0$ and $\alpha = 1/2$. Therefore we look at:
$$
I^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x) := \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}} d t
$$
Suppose $I^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Can we then conclude $f=0$ a.e.?

My approach so far has been to take the Fourier transform and use the convolution theorem. I cannot conclude because I do not know if $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Otherwise, I could conclude just by using the fact that the Fourier transform is an isometry between $L^2$ spaces. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444988/riemann-liouville-integral-of-f-is-zero-implies-f-0-a-e) for the same question on MathOverflow.

Comment: You should be able to use any existing proof that $\int_a^x f(t) dt \equiv 0 \implies f(t) = 0 a.e.$, e.g. the one in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/if-int-0x-f-dm-is-zero-everywhere-then-f-is-zero-almost-everywhere), as long as $f(x)$ is a measurable function.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f \in L^{1}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. First, use that (property of Riemann-Liouville integral)

$$I^{\alpha} (I^{\beta} f(x)) = I^{\alpha + \beta} f(x)$$

Therefore: $I^{1/2} (I^{1/2} f(x)) = I^1 f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt =0$. Then use (an adaptation of) Theorem 2.1 from [these](http://www.ualberta.ca/%7Erjia/Math418/Notes/chap3.pdf) notes or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274702/integral-vanishes-on-all-intervals-implies-the-function-is-a-e-zero) under the assumption that $f$ is integrable wrt to the Lebesgue measure. From this conclude that $f =0$ a.e.

I don't think it is possible to circumvent the assumption $f \in L^{1}(\lambda)$.

**Edit:** I found an even easier solution. The claim follows from a direct application of Titchmarsh convolution theorem, that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titchmarsh_convolution_theorem) or, for an even more useful extension of this result, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2047943.pdf).

Comment: Theorem 2.1 is not applicable here since $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: You can adapt Theorem 2.1 also to the case $x \in (0,\infty)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274702/integral-vanishes-on-all-intervals-implies-the-function-is-a-e-zero for an alternative proof that works without that assumption.