# $\int_{0}^{x} f(z)dz =0$ for all $x \in A$ where $\lambda([0,\infty) \setminus A) =0$, i.e. a.e., implies $f$ is zero a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This question is similar to the question appearing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274702/integral-vanishes-on-all-intervals-implies-the-function-is-a-e-zero). The difference in my question is that I don't allow the integral $\int_{0}^{x} f(z) dz =0$ everywhere, but only **almost everywhere**. $\lambda$ will denote the Lebesgue measure.

**Q:** Assume $f \in L^1(\lambda)$, $\int_{0}^{x} f(z)dz =0$ for all $x \in A$ where $\lambda([0,\infty) \setminus A) =0$, i.e. a.e., implies $f$ is zero a.e.?

If you know this is true from the literature you can just link me the reference.

Comment: $A$ is dense. Apply Lebesgue's Theorem.

Comment: Complement of a set of measure $0$ is dense. That is elementary and you should provide some context to your question.

Comment: $\int_0^x f(z) dz$ is a continuous function that is zero almost everywhere, hence it is identically zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f$ is integrable, $F(x)=\int_0^x f(z) dz$ is continuous (see for instance the answers to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429769/is-an-integral-always-continuous)). You are assuming that $F(x) = 0$ almost everywhere but, being continuous, it will be zero everywhere.